# When does UIViewAutoresizing flexible Height+Top or Height+Bottom ever make sense? What does it do?

Tags: ios, uikit

What is the auto resizing behavior of a `UIView` that has `UIViewAutoresizing` Height+Top or Height+Bottom? Does this ever make sense? Does one of the margins or the view itself get precedence? I just discovered I had accidentally set a view's `UIViewAutoresizing` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`, and that caused the view to resize to a `0` height when its parent resized.

Answer (score 10):

This is how autoresizing works:

Say the parent view has 400 height, and your view is set on y = 100, height = 200

That means, there's 100 pixels above your view, 200 pixels for your view, and 100 pixels below your view.

With flexibleHeight and flexibleTop, it means that when the parent view frame changes, it will maintain the bottom 100 pixels fixed, and split the remainder proportionally between the top margin and height

So, if you go from 400 height to 300 height on the parent, it means it will use 100 for the bottom margin and split the remainder 200 proportionally, leaving your y = 66.666 and height = 133.333

If you go from 400 height to 100 height, it will still use those 100 for the bottom margin, leaving 0 space for top margin and height, leaving your y = 0, height = 0

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` will keep your bottom margin unchanged when the parent view got resized and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` will change its height proportionally to  its parent height for the remaining height.

I don't see much use of the `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`. I have used though `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` to get a view that contain some text to stick to the bottom of my parent view with a constant height independently to the orientation of my device.